# Take the data from a dynamic table, input as variable to use within a form php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dynamic table that pulls data through from a variable input from an input box. this works great and shows my data in the table. I was thinking of having another column with a link (href) within it to collate all the variables within the table and out put to my page with the form where I want to output the data.

Or is there a way to double click on the line and it collect the data into variables so I can output the variables in the form?

this is an example of my table

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php
            $search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);
            $searchrs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address 
                                    WHERE (`AddID` = '".$search."') ") 
                        or die(mysql_error());
            while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($searchrs)) {
                echo '<td>'.$results['House'].', '.$results['StreetName'].', 
                        '.$results['TownCity'].', '.$results['Postcode'].'</td>';
            }
        ?>
        <td><a class="btn default btn-xs red-stripe" href="myform.php">View</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I was thinking after href="myform.php use?and list the variables, when I tried this it just put $results['TownCity'] etc in the address bar.

What better way could I do this?

Comment: Just thought, would I be best putting the table into a form and then having a select button at the bottom and using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Href will send the variables with $_GET, and as a result they will be visible.

One solution will be to use the $_POST method, which will not show anything on the address bar, thus is safer. You can send your fields as hidden.

Try something like this:

```
 <td>
    <form action="myform.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="House" value="<?php echo $results['House'];?>" >
      <input type="submit" value="View">
    </form>
    </td>
```

Comment: Would this need to be done in the While Loop still? I ask as I did it out of the Loop and the input box doesn't display the $results['House']

Comment: I put this within the while loop and it works a treat! Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Quick question on this, I've just noticed. When the data is returned from the database into the input box `<input type="hidden" name="House" value="<?php echo $results['House'];?>" >` it puts a space before the first character, why would this be? there isn't a space when the data was input to the database originally

Comment: maybe the space is already in the database? Try to trim all white spaces if so.

Answer (score 0):

The "myform.php" page can either:

1. Pull data by the same method as this page (selecting from DB). Then the link should point to `myform.php?search=<?=url_encode($search)?>`
2. Or get all the variables from request URI. Then first you create an array with request params: `$cleanResults = array('House' => $results['House'], /* ... */);`. Then the link could point to `myform.php?<?=http_build_query($cleanResults)?>`. The reason for creating another array is to avoid exposing some sensitive data if it is in the database row.